# svn: copy branch to trunk

Tags: svn

I have an SVN project with a branch I'm working on, and an empty trunk:

```
myproject/
  branches/
    mybranch/
      {there's stuff here}
  tags/
  trunk/
```

How can I copy the contents of mybranch into the trunk? TortoiseSVN complains that there's already a trunk directory. I could delete the (empty) trunk from the repository and then do a copy, but that seems wrong somehow...

---

**clarification:** I have a trunk which I intentionally left empty. My "mybranch" is all checked in. In the repo-browser, TortoiseSVN gives me a "copy" option but not a merge option.

If  merging is the right thing to do, what do I do? Do I check out the empty trunk and then merge into that working copy, then check back in?

---

**update:** Merge won't work either; SVN complains the two "branches" (`branches/mybranch` and `trunk`) are not ancestrally related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do what you mentioned, delete the trunk and then copy the branch. It is a little wrong, but it's because you didn't copy to make the branch in the first place.

Comment: so if I copied an empty trunk dir to the branches dir, I would have been able to merge?

Answer (score 2):

You can do an svn export to the trunk folder and then add and commit.

or...  you can merge with the --ignore-ancestry flag

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you merge a branch into the trunk. The branch usually represents a feature you've branched off for separate development, or because it could break your functionality if not finished. Move and copy are different operations from merge.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `svn merge`: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s04.html

Answer (score -1):

I have just done it in my project. we can do a simple folder copy like operation:

1. rename trunk to trunk_temp.
2. copy tag to trunk

Both the operations could be done using eclipse plugin.  Open svn repository perspective in eclipse. 
 4. Right click on trunk and choose Team >> Refactor >> Rename to >> type trunk_temp.
 5. Right click on Tag >> Choose Refactor >> Copy To >> choose the project directory one level up to trunk. you will have option to provide name of the new directory and type in trunk. 
That's all.

Final result will be:

1. existing trunk is renamed to trunk_temp. you can also create a branch.
2. the tag is copied over to trunk
3. delete the trunk_temp if you created a branch.